# Trying to solve Lady or the Tiger in Alloy

Tags: alloy, logic-programming

I've been trying to solve the logic puzzle Lady or the Tiger in Alloy but got stuck. Right now I'm trying to solve the 4th puzzle which is on the 2nd day.
It goes as following: There are a few rooms and on each room is a sign that says something. Depending on the rules that have been given, the statements on the signs can either be true or false. It is possible that there are Ladies in both rooms, it is also possible that there are Tigers in both rooms, it is also possible for there to be a tiger in one room and a lady in the other room but it is never possible to have multiple creatures(Lady or Tiger) in one room.

The signs say:

Sign1: "There are Ladies in both rooms" and this statement can only be true if there is a Lady in Room1.

Sign2: "There are Ladies in both rooms" and this statement can only be true if there is a Tiger in Room2.

I've tried several things already and this is as far as I got. The problem is that I don't know how to formulate that for example Sign1 can only be true if there is a Lady in Room1.

```
abstract sig Creature {}
sig Lady, Tiger extends Creature {}
one sig Room1, Room2 in Creature {}

abstract sig Sign {}
one sig Sign1, Sign2 extends Sign {}
sig Truthful in Sign {}

fact {
    Sign1 in Truthful => Lady in Room1 <=> Lady in Room1 && Lady in Room2
    Sign2 in Truthful => Tiger in Room2 <=> Lady in Room1 && Lady in Room2
}

run {}
```

Comment: Think about sign 2. It can never be true! Therefore it is false. Therefore both statements are false, as they are the same statement. Therefore there is a tiger in the first room and a lady in the second room.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Creature { Lady, Tiger }
enum boolean { false, true}

let bool[x] = x => true else false

pred rules[ s1, s2: boolean, disj room1, room2 : Creature ] {
    s1 = bool[room1 = lady]
    s2 = bool[room2 = tiger]
}
run rules
```

Comment: Drop disj qualifier to allow Tiger in both rooms, eg?